# How to view the date in biblatex when using the bibliographystyle: IEEEtran?

Tags: bibliographies, ieeetran, date, bibliographystyle

I am using the IEEEtran bibliographystyle and have a lot of web ressources. On each web ressoruce I want the date with the time of last access wich Zotero stores me as *date* in my .bib file.

Her is my rugh latex main file:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}


% Useful packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}


\title{Lorem Ipsum}
\author{foobar}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\pagebreak

\input{01_Introduction.tex}
% more tex files....

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{ZoteroLib.bib}


\end{document}
```

The Format in the .bib file looks like this:

```
@software{GithubComFoo2021,
  title = {https://github.com/foo/bar},
  date = {2021-10-11T13:26:40Z},
  origdate = {2019-11-15T14:42:00Z},
  url = {https://github.com/foo/bar},
  urldate = {2021-10-12},
  abstract = {Lorem Ipsum},
  organization = {{foo Security}},
  keywords = {42,lorem}
}
```

The current look of the bibliography is like:

[image: bibliography pdf render example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some methods changing the definitions of IEEEtran bibliography style, but that is a bit difficult for me.
According to the [IEEE Reference Guide](https://ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/wp-content/uploads/IEEE-Reference-Guide.pdf), the date is in the form of `Accessed: Month Day, Year`, therefore, we can manually set the `note` field in the bib file, which now looks like:

```
@software{GithubComFoo2021,
  title = {https://github.com/foo/bar},
  date = {2021-10-11T13:26:40Z},
  origdate = {2019-11-15T14:42:00Z},
  url = {https://github.com/foo/bar},
  urldate = {2021-10-12},
  note = {{Accessed: Oct. 12, 2021}},
  abstract = {Lorem Ipsum},
  organization = {{foo Security}},
  keywords = {42,lorem}
}
```

And the output is
[image: Bib output]

Comment: Thx for the solution, but I am a bit worried to go through all the 50+ references and copy and paste the new argument... But if there is no other way, then I guess I have to do that...

Comment: Okay, I am using your workaround and chang my bib-file with a bit of search and replace magic. thx a lot :)